Update error from 22.04LTS to 24.04LTS

I'm having a problem while upgrading to the new version, I've searched for solutions but most of them didn't work, tried deleting PPAs and writing that command:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
But still the same error:
This was likely caused by:

Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu  Please use the
tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge  package to remove software from a
Launchpad PPA and  try the upgrade again.
If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade.
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.


Please fresh install or otherwise, don't upgrade right now. Too many people are loosing their graphical interface after the upgrade

@ArchismanPanigrahi Is it still not the right time? I am also facing problems. But mine says network error. Tried both with Ethernet and Wi-Fi, and there are actually no internet issues.

@truth No, this is not the right time. Upgrade path is still messed up

@ArchismanPanigrahi 30 days later is a safe bet? Or, do I wait more?

I really don't know. Check out questions on ask ubuntu after 30 days and decide.
